# Websphere problem with JSP page

Tags: jsp, websphere-6.1

I am migrating a web application from tomcat to an IBM Websphere 6.1. The problem is that i get this error when i navigate to a specific page:

> Error message: JSPG0048E Page failed
>   to validate using taglib validator for
>   http:java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core :
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException :
>   Premature end of file.
>
> Error code
>   : 500 Target servlet :
>   folder1/folder2/page_name.jsp  Error
>   stack :
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException
>   : JSPG0048E Page failed to validate
>   using taglib validator for
>   http:java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core :
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException :
>   Premature end of file.
>
> at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.validateTagLib(ValidateVisitor.java:1005)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.visitJspRootStart(ValidateVisitor.java:465)
>   . . .

and the stack trace goes on

the line of code from the jsp is

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Has anybody encountered this problem ?

Many thanks in advance
Simon

Comment: Might be totally unrelated - but someone got the same problem on a *Weblogic* - due to special characters on that specific JSP http://fixunix.com/weblogic/231099-weblogic8-1-jstl-taglib-validator-rejected-page.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the taglib. What happens is that before compiling the JSP WebSphere Application Server validates the JSP by parsing it with SAX. The parsing is probably a bit stricter than what Tomcat does.

The "premature end of file" suggests that you have a problem with some of the apostrophes or quotation marks and a string never gets terminated. Unfortunately the error messages from these cases are usually practically useless. The fastest way to solve an issue like this is usually to remove the JSP code and enter it back step by step to figure out what part breaks the JSP.